# Write a program that defines symbolic constants for all seven days of the week. Create an array variable that uses the symbols as initializers

Tags: assembly, x86

I am very new to assembly language. Here is my solution to the above problem:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
Sun=0
Mon=1
Tue=2
Wed=3
Thu=4
Fri=5
Sat=6
warray BYTE Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
```

Is the above solution correct? My doubt is does everything go in the data segment or do some statements go in the code segment too and how to know which statement goes in what segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct.

> how to know which statement goes in what segment?

.data directive identifies segment used to define variables and constants.

.code directive identifies segment containing executable instructions. Instructions that are executed in runtime. In your code you have one such instruction. Also you need an entry point in your code.

So you can rewrite your code like:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
    Sun=0
    Mon=1
    Tue=2
    Wed=3
    Thu=4
    Fri=5
    Sat=6
    warray BYTE Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat

.code
main PROC
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```